# Python import struggles

Tags: python, import

I am having trouble uploading every module that I am trying to use.

```
""import pandas as pd"" #works no problem 
""from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport ""
>ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic'

""from googlemaps import Client as GoogleMaps"""
>ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from googlemaps import Client as GoogleMaps
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps'
```

same error for import googlemaps, import gmaps, from keplergl import KeplerGl, import geopandas as gpd

I am following the instructions from here https://medium.com/@manilwagle/geocoding-the-world-using-google-api-and-python-1f6b6fb6ca48 and nothing is importing

Comment: You are supposed to install the module first using command `pip3 install googlemaps`

Comment: does pip3 install googlemaps cause issues if I am using anaconda to access python on a Microsoft?

Comment: Check your conda environment first whether  the module is present or not in the environment using `pip list` if not then you need to open the conda prompt (as admin) and install the packages.